# AWS - Elastic BeanTalk: [error] 'php' not found or unable to stat

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple website deployed on Elastic BeanTalk ( platform: PHP 5.6 ).

```
public
   |about.html
   |index.html
   |style.css
   |+ include
         |subscribe-email.php
         |+ phpmailer
```

When I checked the log, I received many errors related to '.php' not found or unable to stat. I don't know from where these php files were generated.

```
[Thu Jun 21 06:18:52.967190 2018] [:error] [pid 12523] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 06:25:46.354172 2018] [:error] [pid 12742] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 06:44:44.392342 2018] [:error] [pid 12963] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 07:18:12.899793 2018] [:error] [pid 13726] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 07:18:24.145541 2018] [:error] [pid 13531] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/wuwu11.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 07:18:24.925862 2018] [:error] [pid 13418] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/xw.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 07:18:25.689064 2018] [:error] [pid 13418] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/xx.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 07:18:26.489205 2018] [:error] [pid 13418] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/s.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 07:18:27.282847 2018] [:error] [pid 13418] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/w.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 21 07:18:28.081399 2018] [:error] [pid 13418] [client xxx] script '/var/www/html/xxxx/public/sheep.php' not found or unable
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution but I had the same issue. 
I'm posting it as an answer to be able to upload an image.
I found something very similar. Also PHP 5.6.
It was new droplet, recently updated. Ubuntu 16, I added a repo to be able to install PHP 5.6 instead of PHP 7 which is the default.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

Where does it comes from?

[image]